# Is there a good way to add and auto-accept buddies using XMPP?

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am trying to build a iOS app that uses XMPP protocol. I'm using XMPPFramework for iOS.
My app has some restrictions. I have to automatically register some new users (Ok, that was kinda easy to do). Users should be able to add other users as friends automatically too, so I should implement something to auto-accept buddy requests and then be able to see the buddy list. Is there a good way to do this?

I thought about implementing something at:

```
- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRoster *)sender didReceiveBuddyRequest:(XMPPPresence *)presence
```

that auto accepts requests.

But then, how could I add this contact into user's buddy list? The documentation is not pretty clear in this part. Should I use save method from XMPPCoreDataStorage class?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests` property of `XMPPRoster` class. It is `YES` by default. If that is `NO`, `xmppRoster:didReceivePresenceSubscriptionRequest:` delegate method would be called.

P.S: `xmppRoster:didReceiveBuddyRequest:` method in the sample application will never be called. There is not any reference to it in the application. It seems to be an old method.

Comment: 'xmppRoster:didReceivePresenceSubscriptionRequest:' will work only when request from known user(known=already in DB/memory). To accept request automatically, i.e. just you got request and accept it that time only, we need to write code.